# Adding a header to a listbox

Tags: matlab, listbox, customization, tableheader, matlab-gui

I want to know if it's possible to make first two lines (Titles and horizontal line in the image below) always show on top and to be unclickable, to make them something like a header of the current listbox.

[image: How the listbox looks atm]

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is not feasible since this is just not how listboxes work (i.e. it's not a spreadsheet where you fix the top rows). Having said that, you might be able to create something that *looks* like what you're suggesting, by creating two listboxes one below the other, making the top one read-only or non-interactable (or better yet, make the top one a [static text label](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uilabel.html) or a [text area](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitextarea.html)).

Another thing I'd like to comment about is the structure of your listbox. In terms of UX, it's uncommon for a user to choose two things at the same time. So even if this makes sense in your context, I would advise to split it into two lists, and have them change each other within [callbacks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html#bt_7n0m).